# Is there a connector/board for a DJI Air 2 camera gimbal chord and camera transmission chord?

Tags: connector, wire, camera, drone

[image: Camera Chords]

Hello, I have a DJI Air 2 camera and gimbal but nothing else atm. I was wondering if there are any connectors, boards, etc. out there that could connect to these that aren't DJI's own product since their stuff that would work with it is the whole board which is several hundred dollars. Thanks, Appreciate it.

Comment: your question belongs at https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A board, no.

Because these are custom assemblies and all the information about them is in the hands of the manufacturer. You don't have access to that privately held information. Without that information, a significant effort of reverse engineering is required. If you're asking, you don't have the skill to pull it off. Most people who have the skills to pull it off know that it's a poor use of their time. Rare is the person who both has the skills and is willing to put the time into reverse engineering.

A connector, yes.

But that won't do you any good without the board.